# Why can't I press anywhere on my navbar buttons to open the navbar

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
.header {
     color: white;
     font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.header2 {
    color: white;
 font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
 font-size:16px;
 top:-35%;
 left:-42%;
 position:relative;

}

body { 
  background-image:url('bk.jpg');
  font-family: helvetica, arial, serif;
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 70px #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 70px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 70px #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

ul:before,
ul:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  background: #2B2B2B;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #2B2B2B 7%, #333333 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #2B2B2B 7%, #333333 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #2B2B2B 7%, #333333 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #2B2B2B 7%, #333333 100%);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #0E0E0E;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;
  left:-8px;
  display:inline-block;
}

ul.primary li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #3D3D3D;
}

ul.primary li:last-child a {
  border-right:none;
}

ul.primary li a:hover {
  
  color: #000;
}

ul.sub {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #BEBEBE;
  width: 15%;
  display:none;
}

ul.sub li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.sub li a {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

ul.sub li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul.sub li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

ul.sub2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #BEBEBE;
  width: 15%;
  display:none;
}

ul.sub2 li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.sub2 li a {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  color: #000;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

ul.sub2 li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul.sub2 li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #eeeeee;
}
ul.primary li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
}

ul.primary li:hover a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
  text-shadow: none;
}

ul.primary li:hover > a{
  color: #000;
} 

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .decor {
    padding: 3px;
  }
  
  .wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  
   li {
    float: none;
  }
  
  ul.primary li:hover a {
    background: none;
    color: #8B8B8B;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
    text-decoration: underline;

  }

  ul.primary li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    background: #272727;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;

  }
  
  ul.sub {
    display: block;  
    position: static;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: underline;

  }
  
  ul.sub li a {
    background: #272727;
   border: none;
    color: #8B8B8B;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  
  ul.sub li a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    background: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  ul.sub2 {
    display: block;  
    position: static;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: underline;

  }
  
  ul.sub2 li a {
    background: #272727;
   border: none;
    color: #8B8B8B;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  
  ul.sub2 li a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    background: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
.button {
   border: 3px solid #FF4A00;
   padding: 7px 16px;
   cursor: pointer;
   color:white;
   font-weight: bold;
 border-radius: 1em;
 background-color: transparent;
 transition: 0.2s;
}
.button:hover {
 background-color: #FF4A00;
}
.LeftFloatAds{
left:-80%;
position: fixed;
text-align: left;
top: 0px;
}

.RightFloatAds{
right: 0px;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
top: 0px;
}
.adBottom {
left: 0px;
position: fixed;
text-align:center;
bottom: 0px;
width:100%;
z-index:999;
}
</head>
</style>
<body>
<nav>
  <ul class="primary">
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">Hjem</a>
      <ul class="sub2">
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Om meg</a>
      <ul class="sub2">
        <li><a href="">Min Biografi</a></li>
      </ul>  
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Mine interesser</a>
      <ul class="sub2">
        <li><a href="">Gaming</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Anime</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Dank memes</a></li>
      </ul>  
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Min fremtid</a>
      <ul class="sub2">
        <li><a href="">Juss</a>
      </ul>
    <li>
     <a href="mineoppgaver.html">Mine Oppgaver</a>
     <ul class="sub">
      </ul>  
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Kontakt meg</a>
      <ul class="sub2">
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ridallah.halabi" target="_blank">
        <input type="image" src="./fb.png" value="submit" width="50" height="50">
    </a>
 </li>
        <li><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/GlowsyJR" target="_blank">
       <input type="image" src="./steam.png" value="submit" width="48" height="48">
    </a>
 </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/rida-00" target="_blank">
       <input type="image" src="./snap.png" value="submit" width="70" height="70">
    </a>
 </li>
         <li><a href="https://twitter.com/GlowsyJr" target="_blank">
       <input type="image" src="./twitter.png" value="submit" width="50" height="50">
    </a>
 </li>
          <li><a href="index.html">
       <input type="image" src="./ring.png" value="submit" width="120" height="70">
    </a>
 </li>
    </ul>  
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="header">
<h1><b>Velkommen til min side!</b></h1>
</div>
<audio autoplay="true" src="skrra.mp3" hidden="true">
</audio>
<div class="header2">
<h1><b>Rida Halabi</b></h1>
</div>
<div id=".adBottom" style="bottom:150px;position: fixed; text-align: center; top: 100px;"> <script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
   atOptions = {
    'key' : 'e0e18baa700c8ab07e64e121d8070fce',
    'format' : 'iframe',
    'height' : 90,
    'width' : 728,
    'params' : {}
  };
  document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.bnserving.com/e0e18baa700c8ab07e64e121d8070fce/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
</div>
<div id="RightFloatAds" style="right: 0px; position: fixed; text-align: center; top: 100px;"> <script type="text/javascript">
 atOptions = {
  'key' : 'b9f9e2b2af5e4716138c8fe4f97c0905',
  'format' : 'iframe',
  'height' : 600,
  'width' : 160,
  'params' : {}
 };
 document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.bnserving.com/b9f9e2b2af5e4716138c8fe4f97c0905/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
</div>

<div id="LeftFloatAds" style="left: 0px; position: fixed; text-align: center; top: 100px;"> <script type="text/javascript">
 atOptions = {
  'key' : 'b9f9e2b2af5e4716138c8fe4f97c0905',
  'format' : 'iframe',
  'height' : 600,
  'width' : 160,
  'params' : {}
 };
 document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.bnserving.com/b9f9e2b2af5e4716138c8fe4f97c0905/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My site: http://ridallah.informatikk5.net/

The problem I have is that to press buttons like ''Hjem'' (home) I'd have to press either a small space on top, or at the bottom. While the last buttons on the right works just fine, why is that? If you find any other bugs, I would love to know.

Comment: so...you are getting redirected to an invalid page as of now..correct ?

Comment: Which browser it is? Works here in Chrome

Comment: Where is yout code?

Comment: code is in the link https://repl.it/N83k/0

Comment: Works on Google Chrome Version 61

Comment: That’s because your “Rida Halabi” H1 headline lays on top of the navigation  at certain screen sizes (which is trivial enough to find out when you inspect the page in your browser dev tools, so please familiarize yourself with those.)

Answer (score 1):

Your `<div class="header2">` block with the h1 inside is partially overlaying/obscuring your nav. Add a z-index to each and you should resolve your issue:

```
.header2 {
  z-index: 1;
}
nav {
  z-index: 2;
}
```